# Agregar columnas dataframe con multiples index

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, dataframe

Tengo un `dataframe` en el cual necesito ir agregando columnas de acuerdo a ciertas condiciones (que vienen de otro `df`).

El `df` principal es `df_pivot`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mismo tiene *multi-index* como se ve (tapo el resto por privacidad). Además tengo este otro `df`, llamado `df_moving`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambos `df` comparten la columna *CLIENTE*. Lo que necesito es ir agregando columnas al `df` principal `(df_pivot)`, según el cliente que sea. Por ejemplo, quiero agregar una columna de *REGION*, y que me traiga los valores correspondientes para cada cliente (estos están en `df_moving`).

Gracias y perdón si no se entendió!

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien: 
función merge

una columna.

```
pd.merge(df_pivot,df_moving[['CLIENTE', 'RSOCIAL']], how='left', left_on='Cliente - Clave', right_on='CLIENTE')
```

o todas

```
pd.merge(df_pivot,df_moving, how='left', left_on='Cliente - Clave', right_on='CLIENTE')
```

o bien, map:

```
df_pivot['Cliente - Clave'].map(df_moving[['CLIENTE', 'RSOCIAL']].to_dict())
```